# Apple wallet pkpass are receiving too many updates

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, passbook, wallet

The app I worked on got an alert from apple wallet: "Some passes are receiving too many updates, which may affect battery life. Automatic updates for *** passes will be disabled. Choose RE-enable if you want automatic updates to continue." I only have 2 passes in the wallet from that app.
Does anyone know what's the reason trigger this alert? If we send 2 push notifications within 5 seconds, will that trigger this kind of alert?

Answer (score 1):

It means pretty much what it says.  Apple is respectful of user's battery life and data consumption and recognises that a pass update is a high energy activity that the user has little control over, and so if a pass issuer makes too many updates, then iOS takes action to alert the device owner so they can choose if they would like to continue to receive these updates (at the expense of reduced battery life).

Apple's previous policy was to silently throttle updates, but this led to problems, since users were unaware that they were being throttled and would wonder why their passes were not updating.

Apple recognises that developers may need to push content more frequently, which is why you can disable rate limiting on your device via the developer menu (that appears when you have your iPhone hooked up to Xcode).

Apple doesn't publish the criteria that it uses to throttle, and normally a quick burst of activity (E.g. a one-off burst of 2 or 3 messages in the space of a few minutes) would be tolerated.  But if the issuer is sending dozens of messages every few minutes, then you can almost certainly expect they will see this message.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I only sent 3 update push notifications, but 2 of them are within 5 seconds. Not sure if that's the reason triggered that alert message.